# Error in INSERT INTO statement vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to insert data into an Access database and for some unknown reason when I try to insert I get the error:

> ERROR in INSERT INTO statement.

The weird thing is I have other forms using this technique but they work fine.

```vb
Private Sub SetActivityBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetActivityBtn.Click
    conn.Open()
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO PlannedActivity (ActivityID,Date) VALUES (@ActivityID,@Date)"
    MsgBox(SqlQuery)
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivityID", EnterActvityIDTxtBox.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SetActivityDateTxtBox.Text)
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    Dim SqlqueryFetch As String = "SELECT ID FROM PlannedActivity WHERE ActivityID = '" & EnterActvityIDTxtBox.Text & "' "

    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlqueryFetch, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "ID")
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("ID")


    ActIDIsTxtBox.Text = (ds.Tables("ID").Rows(0).Item(0))

    conn.Close()

    EnterActvityIDTxtBox.Clear()
    SetActivityDateTxtBox.Clear()
    MsgBox("Activity has been Set sucessfully!")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Date** is a [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248738) in Access. You might be facing this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627624/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-for-access-2010).

Comment: The first answer to "that error" also uses positional parameters, instead of named ones. Does Access now understand named params? It can't hurt to try positional syntax.