# Registering New Users in Database

Tags: sql, database, vb6, ado

I´m trying to insert new users in my database, but every time the register button is pressed i get an error message saying:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

My Code:

```
Private Sub cmdReg_Click()
Dim sql As String
Dim recordCount As Long
Dim rst As Long
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
sql = "insert into LoginPasswords (Teacher_LName, Teacher_FName, PassWord, UserName) values ('" & txtLast.Text & "','" & txtFirst.Text & "','" & txtPass.Text & "','" & txtUser.Text & "')"

     If CurrentCon.State = adStateOpen Then
        CurrentCon.Close
     End If
  CurrentCon.Open
  CurrentCon.Execute sql

End Sub
```

How do i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement will depend on the column data types of your database. 
But lets just say, for example, that you have all text fields in your database. Then you need to do is remove the quotes you have around each of the values.

Something like this:

```
Set MySet = MyConn.Execute("INSERT INTO Table_Name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (txtcol1.text,txtcol2.text,txtcol3.text)");
```

Try to remove the extra quotes from your query.

If there are any integer values, change your insert statement like:

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES(CInt(txtcol1.text),txtcol2.text,txtcol3.text);
```

Comment: I did as you said and it stopped showing the error. However, the new error that i am receiving is: Complie Error: Object required

Comment: `Set sql = CurrentCon.Execute("insert into LoginPasswords (Teacher_LName, Teacher_FName, PassWord, UserName) values (txtLast.Text,txtFirst.Text,txtPass.Text,txtUser.Text)")`

Comment: This can occur because, you referred to an invalid object qualifier

Comment: how do i overcome this. I have `Dim sql as string`

Comment: So, first of all try to use `sql="insert into LoginPasswords (Teacher_LName, Teacher_FName, PassWord, UserName) values (txtLast.Text,txtFirst.Text,txtPass.Text,txtUser.Text)" If CurrentCon.State = adStateOpen Then
        CurrentCon.Close
     End If
  CurrentCon.Open
  CurrentCon.Execute sql.` Instead of executing it directly.

Comment: when i do that it says: **Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

Comment: Then you are definitely missing something in your insert statement, column names/datatypes mismatch or something like that. Try to refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627624/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-for-access-2010

Comment: You were right, i was missing something. i had to add [ ] to the fields and i put apostrophe back in place as the other question. That fixed up my project. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help :)