# Converting String into TimeSpan and Saving it to MS Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to convert a string into a TimeSpan and save it to my MS Access database. But I can't seem to be able to convert it properly.

If you can check my code below, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

```
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        CultureInfo culture;
        culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        string pNum = patientNum.Text;
        string pFname = Firstname.Text;
        string pLname = Lastname.Text;
        string cpNum = contactNum.Text;

        DateTime aDate = DateTime.ParseExact(appDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
        TimeSpan aTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(appTime.Text, "hh:mm tt", culture);

        string aTreat = treat.Text;
        string aCost = treatCost.Text;
        string aRemark = appRemarks.Text;


        OleDbCommand con = new OleDbCommand("Insert into appointments1(patientNo,firstName,lastName,contactNo,date,time,treatment,cost,remarks)" + "Values (@patientNo,@firstName,@lastName,@contactNo,@date,@time,@treatment,@cost,@remarks)");
        con.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        con.Parameters.Add("@patientNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = pNum;
        con.Parameters.Add("@firstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pFname;
        con.Parameters.Add("@lastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pFname;
        con.Parameters.Add("@conatctNum", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cpNum;
        con.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = aDate;
        con.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = aTime;
        con.Parameters.Add("@treatment", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = aTreat;
        con.Parameters.Add("@cost", OleDbType.Currency).Value = aCost;
        con.Parameters.Add("@remarks", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = aRemark;

        try
        {
            con.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Appointment Added!");
            raiseUpdate();
            connection.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any error coming out from this code?

Comment: Hello. There is a lot of extra code in this example. Consider reducing it to just the issue you are having. Also provide the unexpected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your answers and I was able to figure it out.

1. Access indeed has no "Special time"(?) not sure if that's one of you meant but I changed the time to "Date".

   ```
       con.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = aDate;
       con.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.Date).Value = aTime;
   ```
2. It works fine even if I save the value as a string

   ```
       string aDate = appDate.Text;
       string aTime = appTime.Text;
   ```
3. I came to learn that "date" and "time" are reserved words. Not sure if C# is case sensitive but better safe than sorry. So I had to add square brackets to wrap my column name. [See info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627624/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-for-access-2010).

   ```
       OleDbCommand con = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [appointments1]([patientNo], [firstName], [lastName], [contactNo], [date], [time], [treatment], [cost], [remarks])" +
           "VALUES(@patientNo, @firstName, @lastName, @contactNo, @date, @time, @treatment, @cost, @remarks)");
   ```

Now, my code all works fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like:

```
TimeSpan aTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(appTime.Text, "hh\\:mm\\ tt", culture);
```

For more information see the documentation: [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#Other)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(appTime.Text, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        TimeSpan span = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse a timespan this way. Try using *Parse* and the matching culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime aDate = DateTime.Parse(appDate.Text, culture);
TimeSpan aTime = DateTime.Parse(appTime.Text).TimeOfDay;
```

Also, Access has no special Time, so try (though I cannot test this at the moment):

```
con.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.Date).Value = aTime;
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to use brute force using the *epoch* (numerical zero date) of VBA's DateTime:

```
DateTime vbaEpoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime aDate = DateTime.Parse(appDate.Text, culture);
DateTime aTime = vbaEpoch.AddTicks(DateTime.Parse(appTime.Text).TimeOfDay.Ticks);
```

and:

```
con.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.Date).Value = aTime;
```

Alternatively, you could cut it all by using *one datetime* field only:

```
DateTime aDateTime = DateTime.Parse(appDate.Text + " " + appTime.Text, culture);
```